# Reinforced Learning for Tetris

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I get the gist of how to do it but I can´t seem to understand how I save the (State,Value) pairs with Tetris having so many different states that using a hash map should not work natively because of memory. Maybe you can map different states to one single or is there another trick? Or do I just have the wrong idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table-based RL does not scale to big state spaces - you are completely right. This is why  **approximations** are used, both very simple, like linear models mapping state to value, and quite complex, like deep (sometimes recurrent) neural nets (Deep Q-Networks etc.). In other words, instead of having a mapping state->value you model **functional** dependence between these two, by putting (for example for Q values) Q(state | parameters) = value, and you optimize parameters to best fit actual state/value pairs observed. It is worth noting that this is not just about memory, if you are going with tabular approach you actually need to **observe all the states** to have a good model, while with functional/approximated approach - you might be able to find the actual structure of the state space that can be exploited.

Comment: So I use the observed state/value pairs as my training data to fit the parameters of my function? And in the case of Tetris should the reward be only at the end of each game or should it be after a piece landed? I would think after every piece because in Tetris it is relative easy to see a bad move.

Comment: For details how to do approximation please refer to things like Sutton's book, since there are some small gotchas and it depends on the rl method you are using. In terms of reward it depends on what you want to achieve, do you "just" want something that plays tetris? Then you can shape your rewards according to your expert knowledge. I would argue for something in between - give rewards according to scores. Scores are not given neither after every brick nor after the win - score is given when you clear lines, and this should be good enough.